# the uniq gender returns only 10 values. whereas I need all the unique values

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Problem statement: I require list of unique values of metric **host.name.keyword** from the complete index. Currently, I am using the below query which gives only 10 values but there are more values existing in the index.

Query:

```
GET nw-metricbeats-7.10.0-2021.07.16/_search
{
  "size":"0",
  "aggs" :
  {
    "uniq_gender" : 
    {
      "terms" : 
      { 
        "field" : "host.name.keyword" 
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

currently, it returns only 10 values like below:

```
{
  "took" : 68,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "uniq_gender" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 1011615,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "service1",
          "doc_count" : 303710
        },
        {
          "key" : "service2",
          "doc_count" : 155110
        },
        {
          "key" : "service3",
          "doc_count" : 154074
        },
        {
          "key" : "service4",
          "doc_count" : 148499
        },
        {
          "key" : "service5",
          "doc_count" : 145033
        },
        {
          "key" : "service6",
          "doc_count" : 144226
        },
        {
          "key" : "service7",
          "doc_count" : 139367
        },
        {
          "key" : "service8",
          "doc_count" : 137063
        },
        {
          "key" : "service9",
          "doc_count" : 135586
        },
        {
          "key" : "service10",
          "doc_count" : 134794
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

can someone help me with the query which can return N number of unique values from the metrics ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options you have. If you have a slight idea of the number of values the field will take, you can pass a `size` parameter larger than that number.

```
{
  "size":"0",
   "aggs" :
  {
    "uniq_gender" : 
    {
      "terms" : 
      { 
        "field" : "host.name.keyword",
        "size" : 500 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This might not be the best solution for you because:

**1:** You have to pass in a fixed value in the size.
**2:** Because the result might not be completely [accurate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts)

Elasticsearch docs advice to use
[composite aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-size) as an alternative.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "my_buckets": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          { "uniq_gender": { "terms": { "field": "host.name.keyword" } } }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Passing the size inside terms worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your terms agg also accepts a `size` parameter that sets the number of buckets to be returned. The default is 10.

I would caution you against relying on this approach to find all indexed values of any field that has very high cardinality, as that is a notorious way to blow up the heap use of your nodes. A composite agg is provided for that purpose.